# $routeProvider not showing view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `.config()`

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   var myElement = document.getElementById('toggleMenu');
  $routeProvider
  // route for the home page
  .when('/reviews/', { // <!-- this line is the issue (I think)
    templateUrl : '/reviews/views/home.html',
    controller  : 'AppCtrl'
  })
  // any page now, make sure view is same name as url string
  .when('/:name', {
    templateUrl: function(urlattr){
      angular.element(myElement).triggerHandler('click');
      return '/reviews/views/' + urlattr.name + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  });
}]);
```

The domain route for this is `mydomain.com/reviews/`

If I set the first `.when` to:

```
.when('/'
```

While the url is `mydomain.com/reviews/` the view `/reviews/views/home.html` loads. That is the desired effect but why does it not work when first `.when` is set to `.when('/reviews/'` ?

Also, I want to link the site logo to spawn the home view but I've tried setting `href` to `/` and `/reviews/` and neither work, meaning home view is not shown - confusing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `<base href="/" />`
To your HTML-document in `<head>`. Also, it seems like you want to use HTML5-urls. Try adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to your config if you haven't already.

You should also remove the last `/` in `/reviews/`. Let me know if this helps.